# Local less stylesheets for React components

Tags: css, reactjs, less

I started a React project using redux-easy-boilerplate (https://github.com/anorudes/redux-easy-boilerplate/tree/master/src)

I really like how each component in the boilerplate is styled with an individual local SCSS file. I'm actually porting an old app that relies on LESS, and I want to reuse the styling from that app.

I'm trying to just directly replace SCSS with LESS in this boilerplate and I'm running into an issue I can't understand. Here's a typical component in it: https://github.com/anorudes/redux-easy-boilerplate/tree/master/src/components/Footer .
It has a `styles` directory containing two files - `index.js`:

```
import 'style!./styles.scss';
export default require('./styles.scss').locals.styles;
```

and `styles.scss` such as this:

```
:local(.styles) {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 70px 0 40px;
  ...
}
```

If I just rename scss file to less, I get error saying that cannot get property 'styles' of undefined (being locals), pointing to second line of index.js.
I don't really know SCSS and don't understand what the first line of the scss file does and what would be the LESS equivalent for it.

BTW, I did add the LESS loader to webpack config:

```
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  loader: 'style!css!less',
},
```

Comment: Did you bring in an appropriate loader for Less? The repository you linked shows a loader only for `.scss` files, not `.less` files: https://github.com/anorudes/redux-easy-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack/dev.config.js#L65-L66

Comment: :local is note related to sass is a syntax from CSS Modules. That represent a local variable. In build time .styles is replaced by .styles_somehash_ to prevent name conflicts, etc. Check your loaders as @MichelleTilley says. I dont know if less loaders support CSS Modules....

Comment: @MichelleTilley Oh yes, I did add the loader to webpack

Comment: @JesúsQuintana Good point, I think I read somewhere that you have to do LESS and CSS loader in tandem somehow

Comment: Hmm, I'd expect it to work then tbh. Can you give an example of it being used, and a weback config, so we have some code to work with?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/less-loader says "Use in tandem with the style-loader to add the css rules to your document" - does it mean put that 'require' in every less file?

Comment: @MichelleTilley - I try to use it exactly as in the boilerplate, but get an error presumably because :local(.styles) syntax is not recognized by LESS loader, if I understand it correctly

Comment: It looks like you didn't include the part of the loader config that makes the local part work. I believe it should be just like the other loader, but with sass replaced with less (namely the `css?localIdentName=[path]` part)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there's a couple things going on here.

The first thing is, you replaced the loader for the SCSS files

```
loader: 'css?localIdentName=[path]!postcss-loader!sass'
```

with this loader for Less files

```
loader: 'style!css!less'
```

but they aren't equivalent. In the former configuration, the `sass` loader converts the SCSS syntax to regular CSS, `postcss-loader` runs additional post-processing based on [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss), and the `css?localIdentName` converts this all down to plain CSS after resolving imports and URLS — but additionally creates local scopes based on the `?localIdentName=[path]` query parameter. From [the css-loader docs](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#local-scope):

> By default CSS exports all class names into a global selector scope. This is a feature which offer a local selector scope.
>
> The syntax `:local(.className)` can be used to declare `className` in the local scope. The local identifiers are exported by the module.
>
> ...
>
> You can configure the generated ident with the `localIdentName` query parameter (default `[hash:base64]`). Example: `css-loader?localIdentName=[path][name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]` for easier debugging.

So without that query parameter, you will not get the `.locals.styles` property on your required CSS.

Additionally, you should *not* be using the style-loader as part of your loader config, because you don't want to inject the styles by default; you want to be able to *require* the styles (so you can get access to the locals) and *additionally* inject them. That's why the boilerplate has the following as part of `styles/index.js` for each set of styles:

```
import 'style!./styles.scss';
export default require('./styles.scss').locals.styles;
```

The first line *injects* the styles, and the second line *exports* the locals.

So, I think you simply need to change your webpack configuration to:

```
test: /\.less$/,
loader: 'css?localIdentName=[path]!postcss-loader!less',
```

Comment: Works. Thanks Michelle!

Comment: @DmitryShvedov Great! Glad to hear it. I learned a lot while researching this answer, resulting in [a new PR](https://github.com/anorudes/redux-easy-boilerplate/pull/20)

Comment: Nice commit, I'm gonna do that on my side. You could as well just move those scss files into the component roots folders. No need for the style folder, I don't think you would ever need multiple css files for any one component.